# KeyDown event raised even if MenuStripItem Shortcut is triggered

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I have a `MenuStrip` with an item called "undo" and I set its `ShortcutKeys` to `Ctrl + Z`. On the form holding that `MenuStrip`, I set the `KeyPreview` to `true` so the shortcuts are triggered without having to open the `MenuStrip`. I also added an event `KeyDown` on the form to handle some other shortcuts to perform different actions.

My problem is that I end up with the `KeyDown` being raised (with the `KeyEventArgs.Handled` to `false`) when I hit the `Ctrl + Z` combo for the `Z` part. I understand why it raises the `Ctrl` part but I expected to be "caught" as soon as it became an existing combo, or at least have the `KeyEventArgs.Handled` to `true`.

Am I missing something obvious? is there another (generic) way to know a `MenuStripItem` combo as been triggered in the `KeyDown` event?

Comment: I don't think so, I already looked at this post and it does not use MenuStrip to handle keyshortcuts

Comment: "I set the KeyPreview to true so the shortcuts are triggered without having to open the MenuStrip" I think you missunderstand "Preview Key". Previerw key afaik was the underlining of a letters that can be used to quickly navigate a menu with the keyboard only. It has nothing to do with Keyboard Shortcuts, wich are a totally seperate way to exeecuted the commands.

Comment: Ok, then I have another problem, if I don't set the Preview Key to true, MenuItem Shortcut do not trigger as in any other application. And I don't see the point of them if they are only to display and I have to handle them anyway separatly

Comment: What you usually do: 1) Implement a bunch of commands. 2) Have any given command be represented by any number of MenuItems, Buttons and Keyboard shortcuts that execute it. I am not even sure if the preview key is a property of the command itself (as it might be shared with buttons), or of the Menuitem representing it.